# How to use filter with az ad app to do a bulk delete

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

I'm trying to delete a lot of apps that carry a similar property with AZ AD CLI.
I can't find any good examples on `--filter`

Attempting to do something like this:

```
ad az app list --filter (displayName like 'stack') | ad az app delete
```

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `--filter` like this

```
az ad app list --filter "startswith(displayName,'MyCommonPattern')"
```

Above mentioned command may give you quite a bit of json in output.

You can boil it down to just the appIds or whatever you need using `--query` like this

```
az ad app list --filter "startswith(displayName,'RohitCommonPattern')" --query '[].appId'
```

Sample output

```
[
  "b5exxxc4-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "f13xxxa5-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
]
```

I have shown this example using `startswith` but you could use other operators as well like `eq`, `any` for collections, logical operators like `and`, `or`. Do look at the link related to Azure AD Graph API for more samples.

One more thing that I did try but isn't probably supported is `contains`

**More information**

- `--filter` accepts OData filter as per Microsoft Docs - [az ad app list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#optional-parameters)
- Azure AD Graph API would probably get used behind the scenes to work with application listing, so I guess you could read about filtering and examples from here. [Supported Query Options - Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options#supported-query-options-)
- Here is a general specification, although not everything may be implemented behind the scenes.

  NOTE: I have intentionally mentioned older Azure AD Graph API `https://graph.windows.net` and not the newer Microsoft Graph API `https://graph.microsoft.com` since Application related APIs are still in beta for Microsoft Graph API.

Answer (score 1):

To follow this up from Rohit's literally perfect answer, I added a quick BASH script to accomplish my loop:

```
for fn in `az ad app list --filter "startswith(displayName, 'Azure Stack')" --query '[].appId'`; do az ad app delete --id $fn; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Rohit has the correct understanding and commandline syntax, but in the latest AZ CLI, the spacing between the query matters.

In the future, it should be written as such:

```
az ad app list --filter "startswith(displayName, 'MyCommonPattern')"
```

Answer (score 1):

Derek's answer was almost there for me but I had to use a tool like `jq` to extract the array elements:

```
for appId in `az ad app list --filter "startswith(displayName, 'Azure Stack')" --query '[].appId' | jq -r '.[]'`; do az ad app delete --id $appId; done
```