# az ad user list -o table --filter "<options>(surname, 'brown')"

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

do you know where I can find list of options which I can use with --filter flag on az cli ?

example:

```
az ad user list -o table --filter "startsWith(surname, 'siewert')"
```

I need some source where I can find out about functions like 'startsWith()'

Comment: Do you mean this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http?

Answer (score 1):

One of the workaround you can follow:-

> az ad user list -o table --filter "startsWith(surname, 'siewert')"

The command you are trying to execute using `startsWith` instead of that try to use `startswith` .

```
az ad user list --filter "startswith(surname, 'siewert')"
```

***OUTPUT SCREENSHOT FOR REFERENCE:-***

***ERROR Using*** `startsWith()`:-
[image]

***Successfully run using `startswith()`***
[image]

---

Also for more information please refer the aforementioned [**`link`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http) as provided by @*Gaurav Mantri*, which describes about supported query about using filtering in Azure AD Graph API.

And the below links:-

- **SO THREAD**|[**How to use filter with az ad app to do a bulk delete**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56262378/how-to-use-filter-with-az-ad-app-to-do-a-bulk-delete)
- [***GitHub similar Issue***](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/9216#issuecomment-487224442) .

Comment: this is not what I am looking for.
I was thinking about something like contains() or mach()

Comment: As you have mentioned in the question is about `startsWith()`. I am not sure if we can do the same or not . Let me check and update here.